# Why does onUpdate in AppWidgetProvider reset widget state, for 1 second before it returns?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have the following AppWidgetProvider

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public final String TAG = "WidgetExample";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Log.w(TAG, "onUpdate method called");
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        Intent intent = new Intent("INIT_STATE");
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

I have the following broadcast receiver which is configured to use that action:

```
public class StateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public final String TAG = "WidgetExample";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "StateReceiver got " + intent.getAction());

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);

        ComponentName smsComp = new ComponentName(context, SmsReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        if ("INIT_STATE".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // Lets check state..
            int currentState = pm.getComponentEnabledSetting(smsComp);
            if(currentState == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT || currentState == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED){
                Log.d(TAG, "State is " + currentState + ", matching views to be disabled");
                setViewsDisable(remoteViews);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "State is " + currentState + ", matching views to be enabled");
                setViewsEnable(remoteViews);
            }
        } else if ("TOGGLE_STATE".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            int currentState = pm.getComponentEnabledSetting(smsComp);
            Log.d(TAG, "Current state is " + currentState);
            if (currentState == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED) {
                disable(remoteViews, smsComp, pm);
            } else {
                enable(remoteViews, smsComp, pm);
            }
        }

        int[] allWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting the pending intents");
            Intent clickIntent = new Intent("TOGGLE_STATE");
            clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.backgroundImage, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }

    private void setViewsEnable(RemoteViews remoteViews) {
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.backgroundImage, R.drawable.enabledshape);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txtStatus, "ENABLED");
    }

    private void setViewsDisable(RemoteViews remoteViews) {
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.backgroundImage, R.drawable.disabledshape);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txtStatus, "DISABLED");
    }

    private void enable(RemoteViews remoteViews, ComponentName smsComp, PackageManager pm) {
        Log.d(TAG, "enabling");
         setViewsEnable(remoteViews);
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(smsComp, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    private void disable(RemoteViews remoteViews, ComponentName smsComp, PackageManager pm) {
        Log.d(TAG, "disabling");
        setViewsDisable(remoteViews);
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(smsComp, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

**What I want it to do :**
Simple widget that displays a textview with either ENABLED or DISABLED
Clicking the widget should switch to the other state
Upon switching state, it needs to either enable or disable a receiver programatically

**What currently happens :**
It appears that the onUpdate in the AppWidgetProvider is called periodically (by the android system I presume), when this happens, it seems to redraw the widget as it was upon creation, with total disregard to what has been drawn on the remote views since the widget was created.

Are the remove views updated asynchronously? How can I prevent the widget from reverting to its initial state? It's only an issue when I switch to enabled, after the switch it flips back to disabled for about 1 second.

Comment: I have a suspicion but before I elaborate first some questions.
How many widgets does your log output report (unique widget ids)?
When you click the widget how many times is the TOGGLE_STATE part of your receiver executed.

Comment: Additionally some input from my side.
You are using the same RemoteViews for all of your widgets instead of creating separate RemoteViews for each widget instance. I checked the Android source code to find out if that causes problems because it's IMO not documented if that's allowed or not. I couldn't find an answer but I have never seen any code not creating new RemoteViews, so it might be a good idea to move the RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(...) part into the for loop.

Comment: The TOGGLE_STATE part would just update the component settings and not touch the views while the INIT_STATE part would be part of the for loop (read the state before the loop and configure the view in the loop). The INIT_STATE part would basically be empty

Comment: Another thing to change is the creation of the PendingIntent. The way you do it in the loop doesn't make sense because you are updating the same PendingIntent with the same Intent which does ... nothing because the resulting PendingIntent is identical to the already existing one. They are equal according to filterEquals: developer.android.com/reference/android/content/…. So what you can do is create the Intent and the PendingIntent outside the for loop and it would do the same

Comment: Last but not least I was asking myself why you have a separate BroadcastReceiver when your AppWidgetProvider is already a BroadcastReceiver. Why not integrate the StateReceiver code into MyWidgetProvider? That would be more compact and probably easier to read than splitting it into two different BroadcastReceivers. But maybe you've good reasons for that.

Comment: Splitting it out into 2 separate receivers gives me the option to have the StateReceiver consumed by other components. I have to reset the onClickListener at the end for all instances of the app widget, as I'm updating the remote view (changing text, background image) so I have to do this otherwise it won't respond to subsequent click

Comment: You have to do the remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent() in the for loop of course but you don't need to create the Intent and PendingIntent in the for loop because it's always the same Intent/PendingIntent. Anyway I'd create new RemoteViews for each widget instance and not reuse them. This is just an educated guess but it could be related to your issue and it's worth a try. Also no widget sample code I've ever seen uses the same RemoteViews for different widget instances, which could be an indicator that it's not good practice to do so. How about my initial questions?

Comment: This issue is driving me nuts too. I know this thread is super old, but maybe you've got a solution?